# Sources of Torque-To-Yield bolts?

Tags: restoration, fastener

I'm wondering if there is such a thing as a "generic" torque-to-yield (TTY) bolt or if they are application specific and have to be sourced through the dealer/manufacturer?

What happens when a car is "obsolete" is there a way to find TTY bolts once the maker no longer supports the car?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TTY bolts need to be specific to the application, but don't need to be sourced through the dealership. Fel-Pro makes a lot of bolts which replace the stock bolts in a TTY application.

*Usually* the aftermarket picks up the slack for fasteners. If not, then you'd have to go back to the dealership. If they don't have any, you can got to an alternative source and get regular (non-TTY) bolts, which may be problematic or may work just fine. That's sort of a crap shoot.